# compiz key bindings not working

Tags: 14.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, compiz

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, I have problems with the compiz key bindings.
I use `gnome flashback` and `compiz`, and want to use some window managing compiz plugins such as `put` and `grid`.

Since I upgraded, all compiz key bindings using <kbd>super</kbd> key are not working anmyore.
For instance, when I open nautilus and hit <kbd>super</kbd> +  <kbd>numpad key</kbd>, a search popup form appears with the typed number instead of the a compiz action bound to that key combination.
How can I restore the old behavior that compiz hooks into these key combinations involving the <kbd>super</kbd> key?

Thanks in advance!